# How to Save my Picklist Records after clicking Save Button

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button, saveresult

I am Having 10 different VF page for my Custom Object FeedbackFrom__c.
Every Page having 1 Pick list Field at page no 11 i am having Save Button if i click save Button every records should save Automatically how can i achieve this By using VF and Apex.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck, share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I think this one is related to one of your old question. You can put a reference of that to give a better understanding of the question.